# Running out of RAM memory in relax calculation using Quantum Espresso

Tags: vasp, quantum-espresso, plane-waves

I am doing a relax calculations of a 160 gold atom cubic cell using 126GB of RAM space on one node using quantum espresso. but the calculations fails with out-of-memory error.
I have tried using disk_io = none, but to no success.

Similar systems have been worked on using VASP, what other ways are there to solve this issue. Also tried using one cpu in mpirun.

here is the control section of my input file for your reference
&CONTROL

```
disk_io       = none
calculation   = "relax"
forc_conv_thr =  1.00000e-03
max_seconds   =  8.64000e+04
nstep         = 100
pseudo_dir    = "./pseudo"
```

and K points are 3 3 1.

Comment: Could you attach the first few lines (around 100 lines) of your output file? From the beginning to the line where it states `Estimated max dynamical RAM per process` and `Estimated total allocated dynamical RAM`

Comment: [Please provide your output file](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/417/5).

Comment: What exchange-correlation functional are you using?